# Combine multiple datasets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to compile a large database in Excel from multiple separate data sources.
My overall goal is to create a big table that has a list of Protein IDs with a bunch of assorted information, with one row each for protein-drug matching combinations.

I'm running into issues when using VLOOKUP to return multiple drugs for the same protein ID number. My current formula is this:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A469,drugbank_approved_target_uniprot.xlsx!$A$2:$E$7108,4),"No drug")`

VLOOKUP by default only returns the first matching drug for the given ID. What I want is something that looks like the following image:
[image: Desired Result]

Basically, I want 1 row for each protein-drug match. The tricky part is that there's a variable number of drugs matching each protein--anywhere between zero and 20 drugs per protein.
As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to get Excel to insert multiple rows on a variable basis based on the results of a lookup. Is there a way to do this using functions in Excel, or do I need to resort to VB scripting? I've also included a screenshot of the protein-drug matching data set. The Uniprot IDs are essentially the primary key that I want to match across all my data.

[image: Source Dataset]

Comment: Excel formulas aren't the most efficient way to go about this. I'd suggest trying out Power Query. It should work much better for this type of thing. It's certainly possible with VBA, but a bit of a pain.

Comment: I downloaded Power Query and it's working beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think straight forward excel formulae can do this on their own.  To me you have 4 options

1. Use VB script
2. Manually create your large data set and use data filtering which is already applied to your source data you already have
3. Manually create your large data set and use an external program which you could create using function loops in PHP, ASP, Python or any other programming language you may know which would do the job
4. Use Microsoft Access which is probably easier than option 3 as it is a dedicated database software

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, you should've posted it as a comment